# What does "loves birds and get moving" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> #### Why Learn This Stuff? 1.1
>
> Every introduction to every language book seems to have this section. I don’t know what it is about programming languages that causes such existential doubt. I don’t think ornithology books worry about justifying their existence. They assume the reader loves birds and get moving.I don’t think ornithology books worry about justifying their existence. They assume the reader **loves birds and get moving**.

Source: [Crafting Interpreters: Introduction](http://craftinginterpreters.com/introduction.html)

What does "loves birds and get moving" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"get moving" means "begin doing the thing we are talking about", so here it means "begin writing a book about ornithology". Ornithology is the study of birds.

It talks about "books" but it means "writers of books". So it just means "writers of books about ornithology assume that their readers love birds, and so they begin to write a book about birds". It implies that they don't worry about justifying why people should like birds or the importance of birds etc.